# A conjecture on $\phi(n)$

Tags: number-theory, totient-function, conjectures

Let $\phi(n)$ denote the Euler  totient function of $n $.
Then let $N$ be a number such that $\phi(N)$ divides $N$ . Also let $I_1= \frac{N}{\phi(N)}$ which is defined as the "Second order Index of Beauty of $N$ ".


Then prove that - For every number $I_1$ there exists a number $N$ such that $I_1$ is the second order index of beauty of $N$.

Comment: Hang on, is this a conjecture or you want a proof?

Comment: How large a value of $I_1$ have you tried?  Anything larger than $3$?

Comment: @IanColey I want a proof of this conjecture.

Comment: @ShivamPatel Most conjecturers would be happy to see a proof or a disproof.  What's your evidence that it's true?

Comment: I wrote a script in Python to check this -- up to $n=10000$, the only (integral) values are 1,2, and 3. Working on $n=100000$ now, but the code is sloppy.

Comment: @IanColey can you please show me that code

Comment: Just to clarify: You don't know yet, whether that is true, right?

Comment: @Bernd yes , I don't know.

Comment: I'm sure this problem has been considered before. You should check "Unsolved Problems in Number Theory". (By the way, "Index of Beauty" isn't a particularly apt name for this quantity, in my opinion.)

Comment: @GregMartin I read something like this named this way , so I gave it this name....

Comment: Am I wrong? I think there is an explicit formular: Product over (1-p/N) where p must be a prime dividing N

Comment: correction: The formular yields Phi(N)/N, that is the reverse value

Comment: Why do people want to close this? Sure, the OP should have asked "Prove or disprove", but it is reasonable to ask this question after checking for $10000$ values, and there is a definite answer.

Comment: @Phira that's true and the way it was , I didn't check for $10000$ but I did till $3000$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am sorry, but the conjecture is really false: In fact, there are no other integer values for $N/\varphi(N)$ other then $1,2,3$. Reason:

The function $\varphi(N)$ is a multiplicative number-theoretic function. Let $N = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ with pairwise distinct primes $p_i$ dividing $N$, then $$\frac{N}{\varphi(N)} = \frac{\prod p_i^{k_i}}{\prod (p_i-1)p_i^{k_i-1}}  = \frac{\prod p_i }{ \prod (p_i-1)}.$$

Now compare prime factors of the numerator and the denominator:

- If $N$ is divisible by $3$, then there is a $2$ in the denominator, canceling the only remaining $2$ in the numerator. This means that there cannot be another prime factor of $N$ other than $2,3$. So $N/\varphi(N)=3$ is the only integer value in this case, obtained by any $N$ of the form $2^k3^j$.
- Suppose $N$ is divisible by a prime $>3$ and let $p$ be the lowest such prime. Then there is $p-1$ in the denominator which must be canceled by primes in the numerator lower than $p$. But as we have already ruled out $3$, there is only a single $2$ in the numerator remaining as a possible factor of $p-1$, a contradiction.
- The only remaining value is $N/\varphi(N) = 1$ for $n=1$ and $N/\varphi(N) = 2$ for $N = 2^k$.

---

EDIT

By the way, as this was discussed alongside: Here is my recommendation for calculation of many values of $\varphi(N)$: use Sieves.

```
N = 10**8
BeautyIndex = set([1])
PHI = numpy.arange(N)

for i in xrange(2,N):
   if PHI[i]==i:#i is prime
     PHI[i::i]*=i-1
     PHI[i::i]/=i
   if i%PHI[i]==0:
     BeautyIndex.add(i)
print BeautyIndex
```

Comment: can someone explain the second dot (N was divided by a prime p > 3 ) in more detail?

Comment: @Bernd: If there is a prime $q \mid N$ with $q > 3$, then the corresponding factor in the denominator is $q-1$, which is even. Now this must be canceled by some term in the numerator, and hence after this cancellation the numerator is now odd. Our fraction now looks like $(q \cdot \prod p_i) / ((q-1)/2 \cdot k)$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and the product runs over all primes except for $2$ and $q$. Note that $k = \prod (p_i-1)$ is even as long as $k \neq 1$. I claim that if $k = 1$, then the fraction is not an integer. This is clear since in this case there are...

Comment: ... no other prime factors $p_i$ and of course $q / ((q-1)/2)$ is not an integer. Thus $k \neq 1$ and there is some other prime factor $p_i$. But then the denominator is even and the numerator is odd, the resulting fraction can not be an integer.

Comment: @rghthndsd: Thank you very much

Comment: I really understand what you are saying and get YOUR proof. Is this the same as in the answer under dot 2? I still don't understand the sentence "But as we have already ruled out 3, there is only a 2 remaining in the numerator, a contradiction." because the only 2 remaining would be in the denominator, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Bernd: I believe so. Indeed, everything I wrote was inspired by benh and not my own idea, although I did not get it at first either. I think the sentence you quoted should read "But as we have already ruled out 3, and there is only a (single) 2 in the numerator, a contradiction." In other words, if you remove the word "remaining" and note that $p \neq 3$ implies there are two factors of 2 in the denominator, it does make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much rghthndsd for your comments! And you are absolutely right, I meant "a **single** $2$ in the numerator". I will change that in my post. @Bernd My initial reasoning is as follows: we consider the prime factors of $p-1$. As $p$ is the lowest prime $>3$ dividing $N$, the only two factors in the numerator that could divide $p-1$ are $2$ and $3$. But if there was a factor $3$ of $N$, we were again in the first case, which we have already considered. So there is only **a single** $2$ left as a possible factor of $p-1$, forcing $p=3$ which contradicts our assumption $p>3$.

Comment: ok thanks to both of you. Then I have two further suggestion to make it even clearer: 
Write "N can be divided by 3" rather than "was divided" and add the fact that you pick p as the **lowest** prime > 3 that divides N. By the way: Great proof (now that I got it :-) )

Comment: @Bernd Thank you very much. For some reason I was sure that I had written something about $p$ being the lowest prime... I edited the post, sorry for the lack of precision in the earlier version.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but this won't work as a comment.  Here's the requested code to have a look-see in a slow, brute force way in Python.

```
def totient(n):
  if n == 1: return 1
  return sum(d * mobius(n / d) for d in range(1, n+1) if n % d == 0)
def mobius(n):
  result, i = 1, 2
  while n >= i:
    if n % i == 0:
      n = n / i
        if n % i == 0:
          return 0
      result = -result
    i = i + 1
  return result

results = set() #sets store only unique items, so the output is cleaner

for n in range(1,[large number]):
  if float(n)/float(totient(n))==float(n/totient(n)): #integer check
    results.add(n/totient(n))

for item in results:
  print str(item) #shows what we got
```

Update: Up to $100000$, we get $\{1,2,3\}$.